# UDP Client data rate using Winsock

Tags: c++, performance, udp, frame-rate, msdn

I implemented an udp client that sends non-stop 8 kB packets to a server in order to observe the maximum data rate that I can reach, and I'm trying to find out why I can't reach the expected data rate (I observe a data rate of 65 MB/s). In fact I tried the ***iperf*** tool in udp client mode, suddenly I observed the data rate I want (119 ~ 125 MB/s). Is my code below missing something because with ***iperf*** it gives the expected data rate while with my udp client it does not?

*Thank you for your help*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define SERVER "192.168. 1.1"   
#define MSGLEN 8192 
#define SERVER_PORT 4004

int main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s_send;
    char message[MSGLEN];

    // initialising message to a random data 
    for( int i = 0 ; i < MSGLEN ; i ++) message[i] = 'R';

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(0x202,&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");


    s_send = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    
    if ( s_send == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("socket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //setup address structure
    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
    
    if(connect(s_send, (const struct sockaddr*) &si_other, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("connect falled %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(1)
    {   
        if (send(s_send, message, sizeof(message) , 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    
    closesocket(s_send);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try different package sizes..?

Comment: Your code after the `while(1)` loop will never be executed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl . I tried and it increments the data rate but i really want to be a 8k packets. In fact with iperf the default size of an udp packet is 8k.

Comment: A packet is not only your data, it has headers. More smaller packets have bigger overhead (but a smaller chance of transmission failure). And from some experience with boost::asio (lots of years ago) I can remember using double buffers with buffer sizes equal to DMA buffer sizes also improve performance (fill one buffer while the other one is being sent).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I am checking my data rate using "Resmon" . In fact "Resmon" shows the total data rate, taking into account packet's header. In addition like I said to jesper juhl, iperf has a default packet size of 8k and it can reach the expected data rate.

Comment: Ok, tbh I am not that familiar with unix/linux tools (yet)

Comment: @PepijnKramer . In fact I am using windows. Do you have a reference on how to implement what you've said before **fill one buffer while the other one is being sent** using windows APIs.

Comment: I don't I've an example, code was written something about 5 yeads ago for my company. I didn't use the windows API but I did use boost::asio, If I remember correctly you can ask that for the optimal buffer size. Double buffering described in many other places too. (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) I could get 9.98Gbs transfer on a 10Gbs network link (at 4% cpu load). So boost::asio does a god job